# How to get Items from Database to Combobox and textBox

Tags: c#

I have a table from Sqlite:

`KHACHHANG(id,name,email,phone,address)`.

I want to create a windows form which show a combobox of KHACHHANG.name , when I choose a name in that list . Another textboxes ( Email,Phone,Address ) will auto fill in :)
Thanks so much .

Answer (score 1):

See if [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx) can get you started. There is an example at the bottom.

Comment: I don't see any related database. I know how to add an items to combobox. I've read there's a way using dataset / databinding even inside designer. Thanks for quick reply.